# Copy to clipboard in a Safari extension?

Tags: macos, clipboard, safari-extension

In a (Mac) Safari extension, is it possible to programmatically copy some text to OS X clipboard?

All the working solutions I have found requires Flash, which in this context is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume what I feared is true: it is currently not possible.
I would love to see things change, and this answer to be invalid!

Comment: The reason would be security issues most likely.

Answer (score 0):

I've not built a Safari Extension, but you can programmatically copy to the clipboard in dashboard widgets using pbcopy. There is an example here http://andrew.hedges.name/widgets/dev/

Comment: How do I call pbcopy? I do not know an equivalent to widget.system for a Safari extension (and I don't think it exists).

Comment: pbcopy is available from the shell so I suppose unless you could wrap it in AppleScript somehow its not going to be of much use to you.

Have you tried using the Pasteboard handlers http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/CopyAndPaste.html

Comment: Handlers allow me to override what happens in a paste/copy operation, but I still can't manipulate the clipboard there.

Comment: And AppleScript is also not available from the Safari-extension world.